# Debug with breakpoint in JavaScript with ASP.NET in VS2013:

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, debugging

I'd like to step through some javascript code in visual studio.  Except when I place a debug point in the javascript file, the code does not stop at this point.

Things I've tried:

1. Set the internet explorer debug options
   [image]
2. Use the keyword "debugger;"

[image]

3. Add localhost as a trusted site, as suggested in a comment

The javascript runs because the custom alert pops-up in IE.

What am I missing that prevents this from working?  (Running IE11 on Windows 7 with VS2013)  Any help appreciated, I'm dizzy from googling!

Comment: I had some problems before using vs js debugger, I found easier using chrome/ff/ie debugger, press f12 on the browser and on the scripts tab you can set a breakpoint

Comment: Make sure localhost is a 'Trusted Site'.  Run your program under the debugger, in IE go to Tools, Internet Options, Security.